# Skip "Press any key to continue" GitBash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm running a function in GitBash similar to the below:

```
myfunction(){
  build
  runscript
  launch
}
```

The **runscript** function takes a few minutes to run, and at the end requires an input to continue (the "Press any key to continue" message). I'd like to be able to skip that, or automatically have an input so the function will continue to the next step.

However, I can't edit the script to remove the pause.

I tried using the following:

```
yes "" | runscript
```

But that just passed in the input as soon as the script ran. Is there a way to do it once the script goes into the "press any key" state?

---

The **runscript** function is:

```
runscript(){
  cmd "/C jboss.bat"
}
```

And the contents of jboss.bat are:

```
@echo off

set JBOSS_HOME=%~p1
start standalone.bat --debug 8787 --properties=jboss.properties

timeout 40

jboss-cli.bat --file=deploy-script.cli

pause;
```

I don't *think* the script itself should matter - it's just the **pause** at the end that I'd like to get around, without having to edit that file.

Comment: Windows 7. The script I'm tunning is a .bat file too, if that helps/matters.

Comment: Thanks, can you post here the whole content of your batch file?

Comment: `yes` will stuff input into the pipe as fast as it can. Only when something reads it will it get drained out of the other end. That should have worked fine (though might possibly have confused parts of `build` I suppose). What prompt is this **exactly**? What does `runscript` do **exactly**? (Can you show us the code?)

Comment: Updated question with contents.

Comment: But why do you need `pause` at the end? Anyway your cmd will wait to `jboss-cli.bat` to complete.

Comment: It's not my script - all I do is pull it down and use it as part of deployment, so couldn't say why it's there.

Comment: Ok, lets just remove `pause` and see what happened

Comment: I removed `pause` from **jboss.bat**, and the **jboss-cli.bat** file had the line `if "x%NOPAUSE%" == "x"`, so I removed that too. Now when I run `myfunction`, it runs through without requiring any input (the preferred behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "./your_script.sh"

expect "Press any key to continue" { send "\r" }

interact
```